How to add range column over groups in polars
I have:
df = pl.DataFrame({'key':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],'a':[2,4,6,1,2,3]})
print(df)
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ key ┆ a   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 2   │
│ a   ┆ 4   │
│ a   ┆ 6   │
│ b   ┆ 1   │
│ b   ┆ 2   │
│ b   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘

I want to add a column with increasing integers within each group defined by key
df = pl.DataFrame({'key':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],'a':[2,4,6,1,2,3], 'r': [1,2,3,1,2,3]})
print(df)
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ key ┆ a   ┆ r   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ a   ┆ 4   ┆ 2   │
│ a   ┆ 6   ┆ 3   │
│ b   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ b   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ b   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘


How do I do it?

You can use int_range() + pl.len() combined with .over()
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "key":["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"],
    "a":[2,4,6,8,1,None,None,4]
})

df.with_columns(r = pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("key") + 1)

shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ key ┆ a    ┆ r   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 2    ┆ 1   │
│ a   ┆ 4    ┆ 2   │
│ a   ┆ 6    ┆ 3   │
│ a   ┆ 8    ┆ 4   │
│ b   ┆ 1    ┆ 1   │
│ b   ┆ null ┆ 2   │
│ b   ┆ null ┆ 3   │
│ b   ┆ 4    ┆ 4   │
└─────┴──────┴─────┘

pl.int_range(pl.len()) is equivalent to pl.int_range(start=0, end=pl.len())

end: End of the range (exclusive). If set to None (default), the value of start is used and start is set to 0.

pl.len() gives us "the number of rows in the context."
>>> df.select(pl.len())
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────┐
│ len │
│ --- │
│ u32 │
╞═════╡
│ 8   │
└─────┘

In a group context (i.e. .agg() or .over()) we get the number of rows in each group.
>>> df.group_by("key").agg(pl.len())
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ key ┆ len │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ b   ┆ 4   │
│ a   ┆ 4   │
└─────┴─────┘


.cum_count() recently changed how it treats null values.
It no longer guarantees a "unique counter" if you use it on data that contains nulls.
>>> df.with_columns(r = pl.col("a").cum_count().over("key"))
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ key ┆ a    ┆ r   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 2    ┆ 1   │
│ a   ┆ 4    ┆ 2   │
│ a   ┆ 6    ┆ 3   │
│ a   ┆ 8    ┆ 4   │
│ b   ┆ 1    ┆ 1   │
│ b   ┆ null ┆ 1   │ # <-
│ b   ┆ null ┆ 1   │ # <-
│ b   ┆ 4    ┆ 2   │
└─────┴──────┴─────┘


I wanted to use pl.arange but could not figure how to get the start and the end arguments dynamically. Your syntax pl.int_range(pl.len()), can you please shed some light on how it works or maybe point me in the right direction to read up on it

arange was renamed to int_range - I've expanded on pl.len() some more - does that help?

It is just that the syntax pl.int_range(pl.len()) is not intuitive to me since there is nothing to compute the length of. It is just a simple pl.len() without argument to it. Also, According to the function signature of pl.int_range shouldn't pl.len() be passed to the start argument?

ohh I see.. if there is no end (that is if it is None), then the value of start is used at as the end and the start is set to 0

df.with_columns(r = pl.arange(pl.col("a").len()).over("key") + 1) I can understand what this is doing intuitively and can extend the syntax to other scenarios without thinking about it .. been using polars for just 4-5 days. Hopefully, I'll get a hang of it over time. The library is incredibly wonderful (is an understatement)

pl.len() without args gives the length of the current "context", e.g. "column length" or "group length". Yeah, it ends up as shorthand syntax for pl.int_range(start=0, end=pl.len())

If you explicitly add an index first, you can avoid any null issue with your cum_count approach: df.with_row_index("r").with_columns(pl.col("r").cum_count().over("key")) but it is a bit "wordy".

Found the answer on a github issue with polars: use cum_count
df.with_columns(pl.col('c').cum_count().over("key").alias("r"))

